# magnific pop-up - zoom gallery: inline element max-height

Tags: android, css, magnific-popup

I noticed that on the magnific popup description page http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/ the pop-up images come with an inline element of *max-height* (e.g.610px), while on my implementation the the same element on the same screen displays *max-height* as 7241px - obviously the document height -, which leads to a wrong display of img height.
Certainly I can force this with the *img.mfp-img* tag and set max-height, but I don't consider this the right solution. May be I am overlooking something and asking just a stupid question. So far yet I could not find a solution.

And as a second issue while the pop-up images display well on Android mobile in portrait mode - again the image height issue occurs again as soon as I turn the device to landscape i.e. images are not fitting. This does not happen on the description page http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/ - instead the window height seems always read out correctly. I guess this is again related to my first in *img.mfg-img*.

Please someone help me to understand my stupid mistake - thank you.